# How to draw a waveform with min/max algorithm correctly? (like audacity does)

Tags: java, algorithm, libgdx, mp3, waveform

i am trying to draw a waveform from an .mp3 audio stream with min/max algorithm that audacity uses. This algorithm calculate the min and max values from a "chunk" of samples and draw a vertical line between the two points. I can draw the waveform this way almost correctly, but with some errors. here is an image:
[waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMkhp.png)

As you can see, at the beginning the waveform is drawing itself correctly, but then "blank spaces" start to appear, Like if i was avoiding drawing some lines. I can't find the error in my code and come here to find help!. here is the code:

```java
/**
 *
 * */
private void createWaveform(){

    //Array that will contain all the chunks from the audio
    Array<float[]> chunks = new Array<float[]>();
    //the length of the audio in samples
    int length = audio.getLengthInSamples();
    //the amount of samples per pixel. w = screen width
    samplesPerPixel = length/(int)w;
    //get all samples
    float[] samples = audio.getSamples();
    //this is strange, but divides the samples in chunks. i can't find other way, better options are welcome
    int max = samplesPerPixel;
    int n = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++){       
        float[] chunk = new float[samplesPerPixel];
        int k = 0;
        for (int j = n ; j < max; j++){
            chunk[k] = samples[j];
            k++;
        }
        chunks.add(chunk);
        n = max;
        max+=samplesPerPixel;
    }

    min_max(chunks);

}

/**
 * perform the min/max algorithm of all chunks and creates the lines between points
 * */
public void min_max(Array<float[]> chunks){
    float max, min;
    float x = this.getX();
    float y = this.getY()+this.h/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < chunks.size; i++ ){

        max = getMax(chunks.get(i))*(h/2);
        min = getMin(chunks.get(i))*(h/2);

        Line l = new Line(new Point(x+i,y+max), new Point(x+i,y+min));
        lines.add(l);
    }

}

/**
 * 
 * */
private void drawLines(ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer){

    for (int i = 0 ; i <lines.size; i++) {
        Line l = lines.get(i);
        Point p1 = l.getPMin();
        Point p2 = l.getPMax();
        try {
            shapeRenderer.line(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using java and libgdx

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is trying to implement the same algorithm in java with Libgdx, i found a solution. Do not use ShapeRenderer, instead use Pixmaps and the bug dissapear. If you are using only java do not worry, the algorithm in the first post works fine, you just need to adapt some things because you probably are using swing or some other graphic library, but the logic is the same. Final result: [image: waveformFixed]